# C# creating event handler 'method name expected' error

Tags: c#, events

So I have a class made specifically for holding an event handling method which I want to use in multiple other classes:

```
class MyHandler
{
    public MyHandler()
    {
    }

    public void Method1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Now if i do:

```
button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this, MyHandler.Method1);
```

I get the error mentioned in the title. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear what your arguments are meant to be for. If the event subscription code is within an instance method of `MyHandler` you just want:

```
button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(Method1);
```

or more briefly:

```
button1.Click += Method1;
```

If it's from a *different* class, you either need to create an instance of `MyHandler`, e.g.

```
MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
button1.Click += handler.Method1;
```

or make the `Method1` method static and subscribe like this:

```
button1.Click += MyHandler.Method1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
class MyHandler
{
    public static void Method1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

button1.Click += MyHandler.Method1;
```